# How could get user friends count who also like a facebook page?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need only the number of user friends count who also like a facebook page. I am already make a facebook app for that. And user should have go to that app so that we can received user details.

And then using FQL we run a query

`SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id = 'Page Id' AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())`

But it only show the list of friends who go to that app and also like that page. I need also that friends who like the page but not use the app.

Is that possible?

Comment: No this is not possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using an app with Graph API v2.0 or greater, this is no longer possible to get via FQl.

What you can use is the new Social Context API, which should provide the info (the plain user count) you desire. Have a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/page.context/friends_who_like

Sample request:

```
GET /{Page_ID}?fields=context{friends_who_like}
```

will generate an output like this:

```
{
  "context": {
    "friends_who_like": {
      "data": [
        {
          "id": "8490902464564645645", 
          "name": "Friend 1"
        }
      ], 
      "paging": {
        "cursors": {
          "before": "ODQ5MDkwMjQ2", 
          "after": "ODQ5MDkwMjQ2"
        }
      }, 
      "summary": {
        "social_sentence": "4 of your friends like this.", 
        "total_count": 4
      }
    }
  }, 
  "id": "40796308305"
}
```

The property `context.friends_who_like.summary.total_count` will contain the overall count of freinds liking the sample CocaCola page (ID 40796308305).

Comment: Hello Tobi, can you tell how could we print "total_count"  only?